# How to abtract provider & input components when using React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

I'm building something with Next 13.5. Using `react-hook-form` and `shadcn-ui`. I found that building a form requires too much boilerplate code. So abstracted the `FormProvider` and `Input` component.

The issue is: Everything works but type-safety for `name` prop is lost. How to retain that?

```js
// extended form provider
import type {FieldValues, SubmitHandler, UseFormReturn} from 'react-hook-form';
import type { ReactNode } from 'react';

import { Form } from '@/components/ui/form';

type Props<T extends FieldValues> = {
  form: UseFormReturn<T>;
  children: ReactNode;
  submitHandler: SubmitHandler<T>
  innerFormClasses?: string;
};

export const FormProviderExt = <T extends FieldValues>(p: Props<T>) => (
  <Form {...p.form}>
    <form
      onSubmit={p.form.handleSubmit(p.submitHandler)}
      className={p.innerFormClasses && p.innerFormClasses}
    >
      {p.children}
    </form>
  </Form>
);
```

```js
// input abstraction
import {ControllerProps, FieldValues, useFormContext} from 'react-hook-form';
import {FormControl, FormDescription, FormField, FormItem, FormMessage} from "@/components/ui/form";
import {ReactNode} from "react";

type InputExtProps = {
  name: string; // ------------------- here it is, using: string
  render: ControllerProps['render'];
  fieldDescription?: ReactNode;
  hideErrorMsg?: boolean;
};

const InputExt = (props: InputExtProps) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <FormField
      control={control}
      name={props.name}
      render={(data) => (
        <FormItem>
          <FormControl>
            {props.render(data)}
          </FormControl>
          {
            props.fieldDescription && (
              <FormDescription>
                {props.fieldDescription}
              </FormDescription>
            )
          }

          {/*show error msg*/}
          {
            !props.hideErrorMsg && data.formState.errors[props.name] && (
              <FormMessage>
                {data.formState.errors[props.name]?.message?.toString()}
              </FormMessage>
            )
          }
        </FormItem>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default InputExt;
```

```js
// more simpler abstraction
import {ReactNode} from "react";
import {Input, InputProps} from "@/components/ui/input";
import InputExt from './InputExt';

type InputTextProps = {
  name: string; // ------------------- here it is, using: string again
  helpText?: ReactNode;
} & InputProps;

const InputText = (props: InputTextProps) => {
  const {
    name,
    helpText = null,
    children,
    ...inputProps
  } = props;

  return (
    <InputExt
      name={name}
      fieldDescription={helpText}
      render={(d) => {
        return (
          <Input {...inputProps} {...d.field}>
            {children}
          </Input>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default InputText;
```

```js
// usage in component
<FormProviderExt form={form} submitHandler={handleSignup}>
    <InputText
          name="fdx" // need type-safety here
          placeholder="FD"
          className="py-6 bg-gray-100 border-2 border-gray-300 my-6"
        />
</FormProviderExt>
```

I understand that why type-safety is lost. Because I'm using `string` as  type of `name` so that lost but I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [the `useController` type](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/dd89833e9f8abc3c09e12be68b2e6356e473a4a5/src/useController.ts#L50C1-L51C67) to try to re-implement the way React Hook Form handles the field name type-safety.

```
import type { FieldValues, FieldPath } from "react-hook-form"

type InputProps<TFieldValues extends FieldValues> = {
  name: TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues>
}
```